# Whats the best way to round an odd number to an even one?

Tags: python, math, integer, rounding, legacy

I was rewritting some legacy code, when I stumbled into the following:

`rounded_val = (len(src_string) / 2) * 2`

This takes advantage of [integer division behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075837/2-3-returns-0-in-python-why), to round the length value of the string, if odd, to the **first even value before it**. But integer division is about to change on Python 3, and I need to change this line.

What is the optimal way to do this?

Comment: Do you want odd numbers to round up or down?

Comment: Down, it's in the question.

Comment: You know how they say *premature optimization is the root of all evil?* The difference between the "slow" function in your question and the selected answer is 0.1 *microseconds*. Even if you performed one million of these computations in succession, the performance difference is a mere 100 milliseconds. The selected answer is clever, but if there's a chance your coworkers will not understand bit math, use the more explicit floor-division operator.

P.S. don't say "this looks faster" -- prove it. Python has a [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module specifically for this.

Comment: @nemec It's not about being faster, it was because when Python 3 comes along and hit's that line with a string of length 3, it would not realise a floor division but an actual division and shit would hit the fan. Also it's probably common sense/knowledge that bit operations are faster than math ones. I have yet to see a case where they aren't. If my coworker's can't understand something that should make them want to learn. In the end, that answer is great, optimal, and as you said yourself: *faster*, even if by a microsecond.

Comment: The floor division operator (//) is *exactly* the original behavior of Python 2's normal division operator. I'm not sure why you would think it's "less compatible" to do it that way.

Comment: @nemec I'm not saying using `//` is less compatible, I'm saying that the original line (that used `/`) is, as it will break with Python 3. I never said floor division was a bad way to do it, it's been working out since **1997** on this legacy script (yes, it is *that* old). What I did say is that the bit operation is a *better* way to do it, but for some reason that's gotten your butt itchy...

Comment: Did I misinterpret you? *"Then I thought of using the original idea but with the floor division operator //, and thought it might be less compatible to do it this way..."* My point is that if it's been working since 1997 with that exact algorithm, why change? Yes, you need to update the code to use "//" for Py3k, but on a Python bytecode-level it's the exact same computation.

Comment: I said that because I'm not sure in which version of Python `//` was introduced, and it might break on older versions. I changed it because it is my job to make sure legacy code is up-to-date, and was interested in a good alternative for the line. Now could you stop making such a fuss about my preferred answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
rounded_val = len(src_string) & (-2)
```

Although it is sometimes not obvious to someone not familiar with binary arithmetic.

Comment: Yep I saw AShelly submission after I submitted mine.  He beat me by a whole minute.

Comment: @AShelly beat you to the punchline but since your answer requires less operations, for the sake of the community, I shall mark yours as correct.

Comment: Although these are equivalent, from a maintenance point of view, I'd prefer to see `~1` over `-2`.  I know intuitively what bit pattern "Not 1" represents, while I've got to think about "minus 2"

Answer (score 19):

Use `//` floor division instead if you don't like relying on the Python 2 `/` behaviour for integer operands:

```
rounded_val = (len(src_string) // 2) * 2
```

Comment: The problem is not that I don't like it, is that the division behaviour will change in Python 3 and would break that line.

Comment: @LuizBerti: sure, if you want your code to be compatible across versions, then using `//` instead of `/` is absolutely the way to go.

Comment: @LuizBerti: although bit masking with negative 1 is cute too.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe

```
rounded_val = len(src_string) & ~1
```

This simply clears the 1s bit, which is exactly what you need.  Only works for `int`s, but len should always be integer.

Comment: I love the way you think my dear sir, bitwise operators are probably faster than math ones. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The `//` operator is probably your best bet, but you could also use the `divmod` function:

```
rounded_val = divmod(len(src_string), 2)[0] * 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not this:

```
rounded_val = len(src_string) - len(src_string) % 2
```